# aptitude search doesn't see deb, but it exist in repo: http://http.kali.org/pool/main/s/simplejson/

Tags: package-management, repository, aptitude, kali-linux

OS: Kali Linux 64 bit ISO 1.0.9 www.kali.org/downloads/

package: `python3-simplejson`

Here is: http://http.kali.org/pool/main/s/simplejson/

```
python3-simplejson_3.6.3-1_amd64.deb    24-Aug-2014 01:57   54K
```

I'm trying to install it, but `aptitude` doesn't see it:

```
# aptitude search simplejson
i A python-simplejson  - simple, fast, extensible JSON encoder/decoder for Python
v   python2.6-simplejson  -
v   python2.7-simplejson
```

Everything on the OS are by default:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Update done:

```
# apt-get update
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://http.kali.org kali Release.gpg
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates Release
Hit http://http.kali.org kali Release
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main Sources
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Sources
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Sources
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/main Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

Am I right this line: `Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main amd64 Packages` ?

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt never searches directly under `pool`, it only looks if referred from `dists/kali/main/binary-amd64/Packages` or whatever.

Comment: As always, very short answers, even though they may be entirely correct, often benefit from linking to documentation or external sources which support the proposed answer.

Comment: @o11c, you are right. `cat Packages  | grep simplejson | grep python3` - nothing. Should I ask again another question, how to fix it? Or you could help me here.

Comment: @o11c, I see here is Unstable branch, with `python3-simplejson` in http://http.kali.org/dists/unstable/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Comment: @litigious.formalism then the package is only available in Debian unstable, which happens to have a mirror on the same site. Such repos [cannot be mixed](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories); you could ask the devs to add it to `kali-bleeding-edge` and then using apt pinning to make sure you get nothing else from that repo ... or you could just install it with `pip3`

Comment: @o11c, looks like this is impossible in current Kali's environment. Because: pip3 of python3.2 has broken simplejson, there is incompatibility by utf8, storm of tickets, etc, need an upgrade to python3.4. Probably, asking of the devs is only good, short, tiny and easiest way.